# How to alter Column comment in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i am changing column comment in MySQL then why whole column definition get updated.
For example:
i am having `column_name = 'payment_status' default='pending' comment='1'`
if i want to change comment to '0' then why whole column definition get affected. After alter query column definition changes to following values:
`column_name='payment_status' default=null comment='0'`.
my question is : why default value get null if i just update comment of column.?

Thanks

Comment: are you changing it with `MODIFY COLUMN` ? if yes i think you need to specify all parameters again, `DEFAULT` too.

Comment: from [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) : `When you use CHANGE or MODIFY, column_definition must include the data type and all attributes that should apply to the new column, other than index attributes such as PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE. Attributes present in the original definition but not specified for the new definition are not carried forward. `

Comment: i tried both...CHANGE as well as MODIFY..but both query changes default value to null. is there any alternate to change just COMMENT?

Comment: not that i heard off, read link i posted above. Why is it problem to specify whole column definition?